# Не собирается проект Qt Creator

Tags: c++, linux, qtcreator, linux-mint

Здравствуйте. Появилась надобность в изучении компьютерной графики в среде qt. Написал для теста небольшую программку для вывода круга.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPointF center = QPointF(width()/2,height()/2);
    double radius = width()/4;
    painter.setBrush(QColor(244,244,244));
    painter.drawEllipse(center,radius,radius);
}
```

При сборке проекта столкнулся с такими ошибками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Работаю с Qt в Linux. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Наверное надо поставить libGL или как там она называется.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev ?